# How to set up animation plot in pdf output of Knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I want to test whether the animation works in pdf output from .Rmd file (see the figure below).
I have installed the FFmpeg with `brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx` on my Mac OS and `sudo tlmgr install animate` typed in terminal indicates that the animate package is already available for my Tex (`tlmgr install: package already present: animate`). However, the command listed below seems not work yet,although it works fine if I replace **pdf_document** with **html_document**. What might be the problem for this? I have pasted the error information in the final section (I have referred to a related question here: [Plot animation in knitr rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476119/plot-animation-in-knitr-rmarkdown)).

````
---
title: "Example"
author: ""
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{animate}
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r,fig.show='animate', out.width = ''}
for(i in 1:10) plot(rnorm(10))
 ```

---
````

output file: test.knit.md

! Missing number, treated as zero.
 
                   \relax 
l.133 ...les/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-}{1}{10}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted

[image: a figure demo]

Answer (score 1):

PDF doesn't support animations, except MOV apparently. The first couple of google results for 'PDF gif support' are informative, including this stackoverflow question: [Is it possible to embed animated GIFs in PDFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009771/is-it-possible-to-embed-animated-gifs-in-pdfs)

Comment: it should be possible to have animation in PDF right, for example, I have seen a figure like the one I added in the edited question.