# Using LaTeX animate package in RMarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, animation, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to generate an animated graphic in PDF using the LaTeX [**animate**](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) package.

## Code

````
---
title: "test_animations"
author: "Colours"
date: "27/10/2017"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: header_ani.tex

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
pacman::p_load(gganimate, gapminder, ggplot2)
```

## Test animations

```{r sample_ani, fig.show='animate', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
p2 <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(frame = year), color = "red") +
  scale_x_log10()
gganimate(p2, saver = "gif")
```
````

### `header_ani.tex`

```
\usepackage{animate}
```

## Problem

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: frame
>
> Quitting from lines 20-25 (second_animation.Rmd)  Error: Could not
>   find ffmpeg command. You should either change the animation.fun hook
>   option or install ffmpeg with libvpx enabled. Execution halted

### Notes

Why the reference to [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg). According to the *[knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/):*

> When the chunk option fig.show='animate' and there are multiple plots
>   produced from a code chunk, all plots will be combined to an
>   animation. **For LaTeX output, the LaTeX package animate is used to
>   create animations in PDF.** *For HTML/Markdown output, by default FFmpeg
>   is used to create a WebM video.* Note you have to enable the libvpx
>   support when installing FFmpeg. Linux and Windows users can just
>   follow the download links on the FFmpeg website (libvpx has been
>   enabled in the binaries). For OS X users, you can install FFmpeg via
>   Homebrew

[ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) *should be* used in conversion to html. Is it because of the RMarkdown's pipeline?

[image]

*[(RStudio: RMarkdown)](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-2.html)*

that forces use of [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) somewhere along the line?

### Question

*Is it possible to make use of the [**animate**](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) package in a RMarkdown document and avoid [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) so the obtained PDF has the following component with conrtols offred by the animate package.*

[image: chart with controls]

*(Not the chart I want to generate but shows how the animated graphic should be embedded in the PDF, taken from the animate package documentation referenced above.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing on a similar answer *[(Plot animation in knitr rmarkdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426353/1655567)* and a [LaTeX-related discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387/123504) I have came up with the following solution:

````
---
title: "test_animations"
author: "Colours"
date: "27/10/2017"
classoption: landscape
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: true
        includes:
            in_header: header_ani.tex

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
Vectorize(require)(package = c("knitr"),
               character.only = TRUE)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
               cache = TRUE)
pacman::p_load(gganimate, gapminder, ggplot2)
```

## Test animations

```{r sample_ani, message=TRUE, warning=TRUE, echo=TRUE, }
p2 <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(frame = year), color = "red") +
  scale_x_log10()
gganimate(p2, filename = "animation2.gif", title_frame = TRUE) -> amimate
```
<!-- Notes on the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240387/123504 -->

```{r convert_shele, echo=TRUE, message=TRUE, warning=TRUE, paged.print=FALSE}
# Extra options for resize can be added
system(command = "convert -coalesce animation2.gif something.png")
```


  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{something-}{0}{12}

# Latex code generating animation

Figures 0 - 12 should reflect frames

~~~
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=\linewidth]{12}{something-}{0}{12}
~~~
````

*The header file is as in question.* The code generates and animated graph with the required controls.

### *Preview*

Snapshot of generated animation with the controls available.

[image: preview of generated animation]

## Notes

- The code makes use of the external `convert` command. I reckon that this is not optimal as it involves converting the graph back and forth.
- As a consequence of above, the values in `{12}{something-}{0}{12}` have to be set manually with the first figure reflecting frame rate (decreasing will slow down the animation) `something-` corresponds to files generated via `convert` that are named `something-0.png ... something-n.png` and `{0}{12}` corresponds to the file numbers.

Comment: Don’t use `require`, it silently swallows errors. Use `library` instead (or, since you’re already doing that, `pacman::p_load` — although I’m not a huge fan of that package).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Now `require` will return nice `FALSE` message if the load fails. I'm aware of shortcomings, it's mostly personal lexical preference that makes me use `require` instead of library, against [good advice](https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/).